# Grabbing Data From Controls In Code Behind

Tags: .net, asp.net

Hopefully this is a pretty simple question for someone to answer.

I have a drop down list control that I need to pull the value from in the code behind of the page, modify it and redisplay it.  The modifying and redisplaying I've got no problem with, it's grabing the value from the drop down control.  Examples in C# would be appreciated as this web app I've been handed is already coded that way.

I'm pretty new to .Net so be gentle and I already did some searching via Google and a little bit on the site here, but couldn't find anything that stood out as being the direction to go in to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the SelectedItem and SelectedValue properties? One of them should be right for you.

Comment: Awesome, you pointed me in just the right direction a quick google search off that info and I got it.  Thanks Daniel.